# JQuery UI Sortable List: UNIQUE Constraint Failed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, sqlite

I followed the Railscast tutorial on how to create a sortable list using JQuery UI.  When I drag the list item to another position in the list, it doesn't save the new order and generates the following error:

```
Processing by UsersothersupportsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"usersothersupport"=>["1037", "1036", "1038"]}
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "usersothersupports" SET "position" = 1, "id" = 1037
SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: usersothersupports.id:
 UPDATE "usersothersupports" SET "position" = 1, "id" = 1037
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint
 failed: usersothersupports.id: UPDATE "usersothersupports" SET "position" = 1
, "id" = 1037):
  app/controllers/usersothersupports_controller.rb:69:in `block in sort'
  app/controllers/usersothersupports_controller.rb:68:in `each'
  app/controllers/usersothersupports_controller.rb:68:in `each_with_index'
  app/controllers/usersothersupports_controller.rb:68:in `sort'
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?  I don't want to saturate this post with my code as the fix may be simple (hopefully).  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Comment: can you get detail of your controller? It looks you have failed in UPDATE statement. It should be `UPDATE "usersothersupports" SET "position" = 1 WHERE "id" = 1037`

Comment: I changed the code slightly to accommodate for this and now it works.  Thanks Muhamad, you fixed it for me!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.